# Android 12 In/out-call notification and prominent chip

Tags: android-notifications, android-appcompat, android-12

According to Android 12 documentation there is special in/out-call notification that will show that called 'prominent chip'.

It's looking like that:
[image: prominent chip]

I tried to use the code from Android example:

```
// Create a new call with the user as caller.
Person incoming_caller = new Person.Builder()
    .setName("Jane Doe")
    .setImportant(true)
    .build();
    
Notification.Builder builder = Notification.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
        .setSmallIcon(smallIcon)
        .setStyle(
            Notification.CallStyle.forIncomingCall(caller, declineIntent, answerIntent))
        .addPerson(incoming_caller);
```

In my application im using `NotificationCompat` and `NotificationCompat.Builder`
but this line `Notification.CallStyle.forIncomingCall` is refer to non `Compat` versions so I can't use the logic of `forIncomingCall` to my existing notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: The 1.10.0 release of `androidx:core` finally adds `CallStyle` support for `NotificationCompat`!

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/core#1.10.0

---

The `NotificationCompat` class from AndroidX hasn't been updated to include this new style yet - you can search `NotificationCompat` on https://cs.android.com to check the latest version of the file, and then you'll have to wait for a new release of the `androidx.core:core` library.

In the meantime, you'll have to use the platform `Notification` type if you want to use the new call style:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 31) {
  // Use Notification with Notification.CallStyle
} else {
  // use NotificationCompat
}
```